# Multicheckbox not being clickable(not getting checked at all)

Tags: angular, user-interface, checkbox, checkboxlist

I wanted to render multiple checkbox in a grid cell.
I tried with formly multicheckbox. But with that, the checkboxes were not even rendering. So I tried to do it in this way, but in this way it's not being checked at all.
Right now, I don't want any event to be done on checkbox, I just want it to checkec unchecked by user. **to.labels** is coming from another service. In .ts file, I am having :

```
public ngOnInit{
console.log(this.to.labels) }
```

Can someone please help?

```
<div class="inline-div" *ngFor="let item of to.labels | keyvalue; let idx=index">
<input type="checkbox" id="custom-multicheckbox">
<label class="form-check-label" for="custom-multicheckbox">{{item.value.value}}</label>
</div>
```

to.labels is like an array

```
0: { id:1, label:'P'}
1: {id:2, label:'R'}
```

I think the problem is the checkboxes are on a grid, so the grid cell is getting active and not the checkbox. Please suggest how to activate checkbox in a grid cell.

Comment: and multicheckbox not clickable ? means ?

Comment: @GRD nothing is happening on it. It's not getting checked at all. I tried adding (click) function on it. It was not even firing

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kvg4yq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html check this out

Comment: @GRD though, it's working on stackblitz. I am still facing issue in my local.

Comment: Share your code and more details to my email, is shown in above stackblitz link.

Comment: Do you still face same issue ?

Comment: @GRD yes, out of 2 checkbox I am getting one being checked. Updating the code for your reference

Answer (score 0):

why you are using item.value.value?  instead of item.value

you could try this way:

```
<div class="inline-div" *ngFor="let item of to.labels | keyvalue; let idx=index">
   <input type="checkbox" />
   <label
     class="form-check-label"
     value="item.value"
   ></label>
 </div>
```

Comment: Because it's an array, "item.value" is not fetching anything. The checkboxes label are blank. The data coming is like "this.to.labels[0].label"

Comment: can you please share the actual ts and html file to understand ?